# too many re-renders on Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement firebase authentication with google to my app. And I use context to share data between screens. But I ran into problem of too many re-render.

```
export const UserContext = createContext({user: null});

class UserProvider extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            user: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
            if (!!userAuth) {
                console.log("signed in");
                console.log(userAuth);
                this.setState({user: userAuth});
            } else {
                console.log("not signed in");
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={this.state.user}>
                {this.props.children}
            </UserContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default UserProvider;
```

Here's the `Application.jsx`

```
return (
    <>
        <NavBar onHamburgerClick={handleHamburgerClick} showHamburger={true} />
        <main>
            <LeftMenu visible={leftMenuVisible} showScheduler={true} />
            <Router className="main-container">
                <Home path="/" />
                <NewTimeTable path="new" />
                <TeacherTimeTable path="teacher-time-table" />
                <AllocateManagement path="allocate-manage" />
                <ScheduleTimeTable path="schedule-timetable" />
            </Router>
        </main>
    </>
);
```

And here's the `App.js`

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <UserProvider>
            <Application />
        </UserProvider>
    );
};
```

Also I'm using `@reach/router`

The problem here I think is because of setState I put inside componentDidMount. The variable userAuth is totally fine. I just can't set it to this.state.user

Comment: when does the function `auth.onAuthStateChanged` will invocked? can you put a `console.log` before the first if to see how many times the `auth.onAuthStateChanged` function is invoked?

Comment: @TaghiKhavari `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` is a function of firebase to check whether the user loged in is change. And the function was invoked just one time before the error shows.

Comment: I think `this.state.user` is returning a new `instance` of the `user` object every time which cause the extra rerenders

Comment: You mean `this.state.user` at the line `<UserContext.Provider value={this.state.user}>`?

Comment: yep. if the value is different the whole `children` will be rerender. even if the object looks the same it can be a different instance

Comment: maybe it is the problem, cuz when I remove the value like this `<UserContext.Provider>`, no error showed. But when I change the value to some static value `<UserContext.Provider value="user">`, still too many re-renders. I need to dig some more info with Context

Comment: Where/How do you use the `UserProvider` component, and how/where do you read the provider value in the child components ?

Comment: there's a component `Application` which contain all the `Route`, `NavBar`, etc... and _App.js_ contain `Application` which wrap in side `UserProvider`. Like this 
`<UserProvider><Application /><UserProvider>` 
I'm update the question for more explaination 'bout my app
@GabrielePetrioli

Comment: @Gr4y no, using `setState` inside the `ComponentDidMount` is just fine. Are you perhaps redirecting or doing something else in some component depending on the context value and that might be triggered multiple times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly happened but my app works fine now.

```
export const UserContext = createContext({
    user: null,
});

class UserProvider extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            user: {},
        };

        // set new user
        this.setUser = (newUser) => {
            this.setState({user: newUser}, () => {
                console.log("new user: ");
                console.log(this.state.user);
            });
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        // check if the user has changed and setState to the {user}
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
            if (!!userAuth) {
                console.log("signed in");
                this.setUser(userAuth);
            } else {
                console.log("not signed in");
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={this.state.user}>
                {this.props.children}
            </UserContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default UserProvider;
```

I tweak something and it worked! Trying to figure it out